# Fancybox lightbox jumps to the top of the page on click

Tags: jquery, html

I am using a plugin called fancybox on a website, clicking on an image to activate the lightbox works fine, but then it also jumps to the top of the page.

Issues was fixed using this thanks to @cowcowmoomoo:

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
padding: 0,
helpers: {
    overlay: {
    locked: false
    }
}
});
```

This stopped my one page scroll able site from jumping to the top on lightbox click. Hope this helps someone else

Comment: Does it work correctly in any other browsers, and do you find when you close the box, you jump back down to where you were on the page?

Comment: In the future you should post the relevant code blocks, instead of asking people to rummage through the entire site to dust up what's wrong.

Comment: But thats the problem? What code do i paste as its a big site, I cant post code if i have no idea where the problem is starting. I would of done that m8 if i knew where to start.

Comment: I had a similar problem using fancybox from a wordpress theme (jumped up to the top, then when I closed the lightbox it jumped back down), and used `noconflict` to fix the issue on some web browsers (it then fixed for all with an update to the theme itself), not so much an answer as a potential option.

Comment: I updated my question with the solution provided by @cowcowmoomoo below. Hope it helps someone

Comment: @dreamsynk you don't actually need to do that as the answer will have a green tick by it and will always stay at the top of all answers for this question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try initializing fancybox with these options

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
    padding: 0,
    helpers: {
        overlay: {
            locked: false
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks m8, fixed my problem, going to updated my question as best i can do help someone else.